# Changing the ORDER BY in WordPress default search function

Tags: search

My client's website has a blog category and many product categories. She would like the search results to include the blog posts, but have the product posts first.

I can see two major implementation options

1. Change the search query in functions.php
2. Re-sort the search query results in the search.php template file

My question is: has anyone implemented this task, what implementation method did you use, and what issues did you have in the process?

I have searched for an answer to this specific situation and come up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would likely use the [`posts_search_orderby` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_search_orderby/) to change the search `ORDER BY` clause, because that way, the sorting would work *with pagination*.

So for example in your case, you would want to sort by the *post type* like so: (well, if the "product posts" is of a different post type?)

```php
// In functions.php:

add_filter( 'posts_search_orderby', 'my_posts_search_orderby', 10, 2 );
function my_posts_search_orderby( $orderby, $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_search() ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $orderby = "{$wpdb->posts}.post_type";
    }

    return $orderby;
}
```

But if you just want an on-same-page sorting, then you can just go with the second option, like so which uses the native `usort()` and `strcmp()` functions in PHP:

```php
// In functions.php:

add_filter( 'the_posts', 'my_the_posts', 10, 2 );
function my_the_posts( $posts, $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_search() ) {
        usort( $posts, function ( $a, $b ) {
            return strcmp( $a->post_type, $b->post_type ); // A-Z (ASCending)
//          return strcmp( $b->post_type, $a->post_type ); // Z-A (DESCending)
        } );
    }

    return $posts;
}
```

That, however, uses the [`the_posts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_posts/) instead of modifying the search results template, but the point is, do the sorting manually after the posts have been retrieved. :)

And if you actually meant to sort by the post categories, then this may not be a solution for you, but the same concept (or hooks) can be used.

Comment: Your reply is very helpful! I will use your suggestions and reply with my results.

Comment: I should have guessed that there is an "orderby" function in WordPress. Running with that, I changed the order to DESC. And, it's working. The site is a lumber yard. Now the wood types are at the top and the how to's are afterwards, when an internal search is done on a wood species.

Comment: Glad to hear that, and happy new year! :)